# AAD AquireTokenAsync Error 406

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, powerbi-embedded

I'm learning how to integrate PowerBI dashboards into an ASP.NET application and when I try to authenticate against AAD I receive the following error in the stack trace.

```
[AdalException: : Unknown error]

[HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 406 (NotAcceptable).]
```

The code is (Where Username and Password are read from AppSettings in web.config):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(GetToken));
    }
}

private async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetToken()
{

    UserPasswordCredential credential;
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult;
    string AuthorityUrl = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/";
    string resourceUrl = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";

    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthorityUrl);            
    credential = new UserPasswordCredential(Username, Password);

    authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUrl, ClientId, credential);
    return authenticationResult;                    

}
```

Any help would be appreciated (This is my first experience with API's and AAD so be gentle).

Answer (score 0):

In most cases this indicates a misconfiguration on the AAD application that is used to access the Power BI service. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/register-app) you can find a detailed description on how to register the application and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgiAUsdnVrM) is a nice video explaining a bit more. You have to keep in mind that the user needs to be an AAD user with an email that most likely ends *.onmicrosoft.com* Mail addresses like *outlook.com* or similar are not allowed,